# Getting warning when submitting watchOS 2 app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app in the Appstore released back in April of 2015 where I had watchkit 1.0 extension.

Now after upgrading I get the following warning when submitting my new updated version of my app that has watchkit 2.0 extension code etc.

[image]

The thing is I have no interest in supporting both Watchkit 1.0 and 2.0. Is this a warning that will show up for couple of months and then go away or is there something I can do in my info.plist files to fix it?

I also got this wonderful email.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XXX". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> WatchKit 1.0 - Your previous version used an extension for Apple Watch
>   but your current version doesn’t. Users who haven’t updated their
>   Apple Watch to watchOS 2 or later may lose access to their Apple Watch
>   extension.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a warning. The binary will get completed which you can submit for review. Apple reviewers also don't make a fuss about it and your app will get approved. Its more like a FYI warning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two separate watch apps if you want to support watchOS 1 and watchOS 2. You need two different targets. However you can share your classes between the two apps by checking `Target Membership` from the `File Inspector` in XCode.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I have already mentioned that in my post and I was asking as to how to remove this warning to begin with

Comment: As of now, you cannot remove it unless you change the name of your app and submit as new app. Nowadays, it is quite common to receive that warning because you already have watch OS 1 in the appstore. You may check the following thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25361